# JavaMail connection to secureimap.t-online.de is refused

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

We're running a server in our sports club, which requests (among other functionalities) our emails from t-online. Since a few weeks, the connection is refused most times.

I search around the questions and information on the telekom-page, but have not found any mistakes.

I made sure, the port and the address are correct: https://www.telekom.de/hilfe/festnetz-internet-tv/e-mail/e-mail-server-e-mail-protokolle-und-e-mail-einrichtung/posteingangsserver-und-postausgangsserver?samChecked=true

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.SearchTerm;

public class EmailTestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String username = "Email@t-online.de";
        String password = "Password";
        read(username, password, message -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(message.getSubject());
            } catch (MessagingException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, Folder.READ_WRITE, null);
    }

    public static void read(final String username, final String password, Consumer<Message> messageConsumer,
            int folderAction, SearchTerm searchTerm) {
        final String host = "secureimap.t-online.de";
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", host);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.user", username);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.tr ust", host); // JAVA truststore

        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory", "993");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993");

        // Start SSL connection

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        try (Store store = session.getStore("imap")) {
            store.connect(host, username, password);
            try (Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX")) {
                emailFolder.open(folderAction);
                if (searchTerm != null) {
                    Arrays.stream(emailFolder.search(searchTerm)).forEach(messageConsumer::accept);
                } else {
                    Arrays.stream(emailFolder.getMessages()).forEach(messageConsumer::accept);
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The could should print out all subjects of the emails of the INBOX, but instead throw's an exception:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: secureimap.t-online.de, 993; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:740)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at de.bamberg.jugger.mail.EmailTestMain.read(EmailTestMain.java:55)
    at de.bamberg.jugger.mail.EmailTestMain.main(EmailTestMain.java:21)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:353)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:218)
    at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:134)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:131)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:763)
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:698)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: "refused most times", does this means that this code sometimes work?

Comment: I don't want to be cruel to you, but you have to ask Telekom. This isn't a programming question, no amount of programming will solve Telekom's uptime problem. Very sorry. Really very sorry.

Comment: Also try these [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug) to see if the problem is with your program, your computer, or the server.  Make sure you don't have an anti-virus or firewall program that's interfering with your ability to connect.